# does norm of a prime ideal of $O_K$ has to be prime?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field then,
 *does norm of a prime ideal of $O_K$ has to be prime?*

I do not think so, but what is the counterexample, couldn't think of any in $\mathbb{Z\sqrt{-5}}$?

Comment: Is it true for $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: In agreement with @ThomasAndrews, I suggest that you should always try out conjectures like this on that easiest of algebraic integer rings, $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ try $I=13\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Prove that $x^2+5y^2$ is not divisible by $13$ unless $13\mid x,y$. So $I$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: It would suffice that any prime divisor of $13\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ must have norm 13, but no such element exists, correct?

Comment: Well, there could be a *prime ideal* divisor. After all, no prime has norm $2$ or $3$ but $(1+\sqrt{-5})\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a prime ideal. @JacobBond